# Polycyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can somebody explain the difference between two definitions of polycyclic groups? 1. Polycyclic group is a group with subnormal series of finite length and with cyclic factors. 2. factors should be finitely generated abelian groups. Why 1 and 2 are equivalent ? Thank you!

Comment: Because finitely generated abelian groups are direct products of finitely many cyclic groups, so you can refine a subnormal series with f.g. abelian factors to one with cyclic factors.

Comment: thanks for answer, i understand this fact on such level, but how to show it correctly? How to "extend" subnormal series? For instance, $G_0 \rhd G_1 $, where $G_0/G_1 \simeq C_1 \times C_2$ , where $C_1, C_2$ - cyclic groups.

Comment: Can someone check my solving in this case? $G_0/G_1 \simeq C_1 \times C_2$, $G_0 \simeq G_1 \leftthreetimes (C_1 \times C_2)$. $G_1' \simeq G_1  \leftthreetimes C_1 $. Then, $G_0 \rhd G_1' \rhd G_1 $ -- subnormal series with cyclic factors.

Comment: I am not familiar with the use of the symbol $\leftthreetimes$ in this context, but I think your argument is basically correct. $G_1'$ should be the complete inverse image of $C_1$ in $G_0/G_1$.